# Unexpected behaviour on CSS3 animation (transform: rotate)

Tags: css, css-transforms, css-animations

I'm trying to do a simple animation : make some elements spin.

But there's something wrong : instead of spinning, the elements are moving as if i applied a "translateX" transform function.

I think the problem occurs because of the transform function i apply in the JS part. But I can't find a proper solution (I don't want to create each element manually).

JS part :

```
$container = document.getElementById('container');
$block = document.createElement('div');
$block.className = 'block';
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    $blockactu = $block.cloneNode(true);
    $blockactu.style.transform = 'translateX('+100*i+'px)';
    $container.appendChild($blockactu);
}
```

CSS part :

```
@keyframes spin-reverse{
   to {
      transform: rotate(-360deg);
   }
}
.block{
   background-color:orange;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 175px;
   top: 200px;
   z-index:1;
   transform-origin: top;
   animation: spin-reverse linear 40s infinite;
}
```

Here's an example : http://jsfiddle.net/5DjeR/3/

NB: I didn't use prefix to simplify the understanding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements aren't rotating because of your `@keyframe` rule. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) you need a `from` and `to` selector (or `0%` and `100%`) in order for a keyframe to be valid & used.

> In order for a keyframe list to be valid, it must include rules for at least the times 0% (or from) and 100% (or to) (that is, the starting and ending states of the animation). If both of these time offsets aren't specified, the keyframe declaration is invalid and can't be used for animation.

Include `from` and just set it's rotate argument to 0. http://jsfiddle.net/5DjeR/5/

```
@keyframes spin-reverse {
    from {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I had a rotate transform in the JS part, the problem still the same. The only option I found was to generate the keyframe in the JS part too, so I can define the transform operation in the "from" and the "to" parts of the keyframe, and juste add a rotate transform in the end of the "to" part.